# how to get the Id from the list of records if user update a value for one objet on the list in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, controller

If i am updating a value of a list of records : suppose 
1. first there is a list of opportunity 
2. after clicking any opportunity , oppli list will show
3. now i can update sales price of each opportunity,

4.upto this there are no problems but how i can get the sales price of opportunityLineitem in a list of opLI and update a custom field of parent opportunity with these and also other oppli sales price under that opportunity will get changed

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ? It is not very clear

Comment: was that question or a puzzle .Not clear

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom class extension and possibly a wrapper class.

I have done [something similar](https://github.com/sjurgis/salesforce-mass-update) before, you might be able to re-use.

You will need to query something like `SELECT id, name, custom_field__c, opportunity.custom_field__c FROM opportunityLineitem WHERE opportunityId=:setOfOpportunityIds`